# JasperReports: Image not found in subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm putting a checkbox image in a report all fine, but when it is within a subreport I am getting error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found
```

Comment: I think you should fix the path to your image

Answer (score 1):

Because if the subreport could not get a value for the image componment.If you give a value to image's Field or Parameter field,then this error will disappear.